# How To Setup Git SSH Server To GPG Sign Git Push Requests?

Tags: git, gnupg, git-push, git-sign

I am trying to setup my private git SSH server to accept GPG-signed push requests.

I have tried to follow Konstantin's instructions: https://people.kernel.org/monsieuricon/signed-git-pushes

On my server machine I configured the `config` file of the git repository on my server as Konstantin recommended:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true

[receive]
        advertisePushOptions = true
        certNonceSeed = "<nonce seed here>"

[push]
        gpgSign = true
```

On my server and client machine I configured the following:

[image: git config push.gpgSign]

`git config receive.certNonceSeed "<nonce seed here>"`

I do the following commands on my client machine:

1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -S -m "Message here"`
3. `git push origin main --signed --repo=ssh://url_of_server:/path/to/repo`

But git prints the following error message:

`fatal: the receiving end does not support --signed push`

When I type `git-receive-pack ../RaiderHacks/` on my server git prints the following:

[image: git-receive-pack]

I looked over documentation for git push using `man git-push` and `man git-receive-pack` and I am still confused.

I am simply trying to ensure I can GPG-sign my git push requests with the GPG private key I set using the `user.signingkey` config option

Comment: If it's your private server, then you don't really get any benefit out of enabling signed git pushes. It's a service that is best suited for shared hosting environments. Overall, these settings should enable signed pushes for you -- if it's not working, I suggest you check that the git version on your server is new enough to support them.

Comment: Thank you for the response mricon. I just decided to clone a fresh repository. This time, the branch I was at was the default master branch. So once I set the git config push.gpgSign to true and the git config receive.certNonceSeed to the actual seed value, the git push reported no errors. I am actually doing this for educational purposes since GPG signing git pushes is a new feature. I just have one question, how do you best verify GPG signed git pushes?